# Loop Lookup - string elements together

Tags: c#, linq, loops, element, lookup

With the help I recevied on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844610/c-sharp-linq-per-invoice-show-string-int-array-of-unique-products-attempt-s), I have a [working linq](https://dotnetfiddle.net/diiRbo) lookup that has a InvoiceID + List of Products for each Invoice:

I can successfully loop the lookup (as shown in code), and display the key,
but I need assistance on displaying the list of elements for each key please.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    class InvoiceProducts 
    {
        public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
         List<InvoiceProducts> list = new List<InvoiceProducts>();
        list.Add(new InvoiceProducts{ InvoiceID = 7000, ProductID=15});
        list.Add(new InvoiceProducts{ InvoiceID = 7000, ProductID=10});
        list.Add(new InvoiceProducts{ InvoiceID = 7000, ProductID=10});
        list.Add(new InvoiceProducts{ InvoiceID = 7000, ProductID=15});

        list.Add(new InvoiceProducts{ InvoiceID = 7010, ProductID=12});
        list.Add(new InvoiceProducts{ InvoiceID = 7010, ProductID=20});
        list.Add(new InvoiceProducts{ InvoiceID = 7010, ProductID=12});

        list.Add(new InvoiceProducts{ InvoiceID = 7021, ProductID=1});
        list.Add(new InvoiceProducts{ InvoiceID = 7021, ProductID=1});

        var lookup = list.Select(x => new { x.InvoiceID, x.ProductID })
                     .Distinct()
                     .ToLookup(x => x.InvoiceID, x => x.ProductID);

        foreach(var x in lookup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

should return :

```
7000 10,15
7010 12,20
7021 1
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(x.Key + " " + String.Join(", ", x));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enumerate `x` which is an `IEnumerable<int>`, you can use `String.Join` to concatenate the ordered `int`s as desired:

```
foreach(var x in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x.Key, String.Join(",", x.OrderBy(i => i)));
}
```

You could also create a collection like a `List<int>`:

```
foreach(var x in lookup)
{
    List<int> productList = x.ToList();
}
```

Comment: brilliant! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This should work:-

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.InvoiceID)
                 .Select(x => x.Key + "," + 
                              String.Join(",", x.Select(z => z.ProductID).Distinct()));
```

[Working Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jzxgkl)